# example of a sequence $f_n$, $n=1,2...$ of integrable functions converging to $f$ s.t limit of integral of $f_n$ does not exist

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Is there an example of a sequence of of functions $f_n$ converging to a function $f$ such that $f_n$, $n=1,2...$ are integrable and nonegative and their integral over a measurable set $A$ is less than a finite $K$ for all $n$
, however the limit of integral of $f_n$ on $A$ does not exist?

I am just trying to understand why Fatou theorem has $\liminf$ of integral of $f_n$.

Thank you

Comment: I guess you need to think of a sequence of functions like $r_n\cdot 1_{A_n}$ that converge a.e. to a non-integrable function but $r_n \cdot \mu(A_n)\leq K$.

Comment: @Ilya: That is not possible, because Fatou's Lemma shows under these assumptions that $f$ will be integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f_n = \frac{1}{n}\cdot  \chi_{[0,n]}$ for $n$ even and $f_n \equiv 0$ for $n$ odd.

Then $f_n \to f$ pointwise, but $\int f_n = 1$ for $n$ even and $\int f_n = 0$ for $n$ odd (everything with the usual Lebesgue measure).

Comment: :Thank you for your response but I don't understand what fn=1/n.x[0,n] means

Comment: $\chi_A$ is the characteristic/indicator function of the set $A$, i.e. $\chi_A (x)=1 $ if $x\in A$ and $\chi_A (x)=0$ otherwise. Hence, $\frac{1}{n}\cdot \chi_{[0,n]} (x) = 1/n$ for $0\leq x \leq n$ and $0$ otherwise.